# Is there a an online copy of English translation of Pramanavarttika of Shri Dharmakirthi?

Tags: buddhism

Is there a an online copy of English translation of Pramanavarttika of Shri Dharmakirthi?

Of the available links only second chapter is available. I'm looking especially for the first chapter.

If the full version is available, please provide the link for it.

Note: Pramanavarttika, even though a Buddhist text, is very relevant to Hinduism as it discusses Hindu schools of Samkhya, Nyaya and Vedanta and tries to refute them logically.

Comment: When we see questions like this most of us search on [archive.org](https://archive.org/). You yourself might give it a try if you can find it there :)

Comment: HI!! Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [FAQ Index for HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange). Please go through it properly. Have an enriching journey ahead.

Comment: It is interesting that this question was downvoted in the buddhism stack exchange. Dharmakirti was definitely a buddhist scholar. His refutation of schools of sanatana dharma was then later refuted.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Was later refuted...? Can u please tell, if you know, the books which refuted him?? As Buddhists even today hold him as authority.

Comment: @Rickross yeah I tried it, I couldn't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a word by word translation? If not, I would advise you to read the book Buddhist logic by STCHERBATSKY. This is in two volumes that includes significant translations of Dharmakriti's work. This is available on [archive](https://archive.org/details/buddhistlogictheodorstcherbatskyvolume1mlbd_821_w/page/n13/mode/2up) but will not come up by search for Dharmakriti or Pramanavarttika.

Two more books I would recommend are

IS ENLIGHTENMENT POSSIBLE? Dharmakirti andrGyal tshab rje on Knowledge, Rebirth, No-Self
and Liberation. This book contains a line by line chapter of certain chapters of Dharmakriti.

Buddhist logic (A fresh study of Dharmakriti) by Bapat.

These books are available online on library genesis but that is not a legal site and I will not link it from here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work. I'm actually interested in the first chapter where he tries to refute the Apourusheyatva of Vedas. I myself am looking for the arguments of Apourusheyatva both trying to prove and refuting. I myself think the argument of Apourusheya is simply wrong. And as a Hindu it concerns me. So I'm searching for it.

Comment: I myself am an Advaiti Vedantist. But the proof we have for the Apourusheyatva is simply that we dont remember who wrote it and its always been said by our forefathers that its authorless. How is this a proof?? Can it stand upto the rigorous proof required by modern Science??

Comment: @Mr Green Gold Thanks for accepting the answer. Please make it as separate questions: (a) has dharmakriti philosophy been refuted by advaita scholars (b) what proof is there for apourusheyatava. These are not directly to this question.

Comment: I know I know its not related. I was only telling you personally why I was searching for 1st chaptrer of Pramana Vartikka

Comment: @Mr Green Gold okay sir. The authorlessness of the vedas has been answered by the mimansa extensively. In fact the exact questions posed above "simply that we dont remember who wrote it and its always been said by our forefathers that its authorless" has been answered by them.

Comment: But Mimsakas answer are just wrong. They postulate the Earth was not created which is wrong. They postulate that humans have always existed. Which is also wrong. And Varna Nityatva is illogical, Sound waves are enough to explain sound and the pratyabhigna can be amswered by apoha. It just doesn't make any sense. And I say this as a believer in Vedas.

Comment: And In the links you have given I couldn't find firsr chapter or Apourusheyatva addressed.

Comment: @ Mr Green Gold The first chapter is discussed in bapat''s book. But only the early portion of the first chapter on formal inference and exclusion. It does not discuss about vedas etc.

Comment: yeah I need about the Vedas.

Comment: @ Mr Green Gold I would still suggest you read Mimasakas reply to Nyaya in the jaimini sutras. it is quite detailed. I agree that Mimasakas are wrong in many details and these have been refuted by Vedanta. But Vedanta accepts Mimasakas in many things too. The Mīmāṃsākas advocate the self-validity of knowledge both in respect of its origin (utpatti) and ascertainment (jñapti). Vedantists also drew freely upon this particular Mīmāṃsā contribution.

Comment: I have heard those arguments. Only two things are used Varna nithyathva vada and Avichinna parampara. Both of the proofs are easaily wrong. There's no proof for Varna's, modern sound waves explain everything. Avichinna paramparanis not true among humans as Earth itself was created. Mimsakas hold that Earth was never created and humans were always there. Which is wrong. What other proof is there??

Comment: Are u from Bangalore??

Comment: @Mr Green Gold used to be. Now settled in Tiruvannamalai.